# What is the process to create an FAQ bot using Spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, chatbot, named-entity-recognition

I am beginner to Machine Learning and NLP, I have to create a bot based on FAQ dataset, Each FAQ dataset excel file contains 2 columns "Questions" and its "Answers".

Eg. A record from an excel file (A question & it's answer).

**Question** - `What is RASA-NLU?`

**Answer** - `Rasa NLU is trained to identify intent and entities. Better the training, better the identification...`

We have 3K+ excel files which has around 10K to 20K such records each excel.

To implement the bot, I would have followed exactly [this FAQ bot approach](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/01/faq-chatbots-the-future-of-information-searching/) which uses `RASA-NLU`, but the `RASA`,`Chatterbot` also Microsoft's `QnA maker` are not allowed in my organization.

And `Spacy` does the `NER extraction` perfectly for me, so I am looking for a bot creation using Spacy. but I don't know how to proceed further after extracting the entities. (IMHO, I will have to predict the exact question from dataset (and its answer from `knowlwdge base`) from user query to the bot)

I don't know what NLP algorithm/ ML process to be used or is there any easiest way to create that FAQ bot using extracted NERs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve your FAQ bot is to transform the problem into a classification problem. You have questions and the answers can be the "labels". I suppose that you always have multiple training questions which map to the same answer. You can encode each answer in order to get smaller labels (for instance, you can map the text of the answer to an id).
Then, you can use your training data (the questions) and your labels (the encoded answers) and feed a classifier. After the training your classifier can predict the label of unseen questions. 
Of course, this is a supervised approach, so you will need to extract features from your training sentences (the questions). In this case, you can use as a feature the bag-of-word representations and even include the named entities.
An example of how to do text classification in spacy is available here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-text-classification-in-python-using-spacy/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the your assumption is not right. basically each question has an unique answer...so labeling answers would not work for me I believe.Is there a way to classify the questions directly?

Comment: Another thing you can do is to measure the similarity between an input user question and all the questions you have in your dataset. Then take the most similar one and return its answer.

Comment: makes more sense... Thank you very much.